# I have problems understanding the syntax of this code. Can someone explain it line by line?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am learning about functional programming. I have understood the principle and now I try to learn specifics. This code is supposed to find out if n is a prime or not. I don't understand what the first line is doing. I suggest it wants an integer to be a boolean value in the function(do you call it that?) 'isPrime'.

Line 2 to 4 are some sort of implementation of the equivalent of the determination if the modulo of n/x is zero with x counting up excluding n as a factor.

Please help me with this.
thank you in advance.

Code in Question:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = (factors n == []) -- (1)
  where
factors n = [ x | x <- [2..n-1], n `mod` x == 0 ]
```

Comment: First line is a type definition (signature) for the function. It means `isPrime` is a function from `Integer` to a `Bool`. So it accepts a number and returns a boolean whether it's prime or not. It is optional but it's a good habit to always put it there.

Comment: [Here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) is a pretty good place to start.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can't learn a new programming language by asking generally about arbitrary bits of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
```

is a type signature. It declares `isPrime` to be a function that takes an `Integer` and returns a `Bool`.

```
isPrime n = (factors n == [])
```

`(factors n == [])` is the body of `isPrime`'s definition. `isPrime` takes one argument, `n`, and then calls `factors n` to see if it is equal to an empty list. That is, if `n` has no factors, then it is prime.

```
where
```

just sets up the definition of `factors` so it is scoped to `isPrime`, basically.

```
factors n = [ x | x <- [2..n-1], n `mod` x == 0 ]
```

is the real meat-and-bones of this program, so it does the most work. First of all, `factors` takes a single argument, `n`. It then builds a list using a list comprehension.

```
[ x | x <- [2..n-1], n `mod` x == 0 ]
```

can be read as "make a list of integers `x` from 2 to n - 1 such that `n` divided by `x` yields no remainder". Which is basically checking to see if `n` is divisible by `x`; if it is, `x` is a *factor* of `n`.

Comment: Okay, great. That was a great explanation @mipadi . Thank you for that. But about that `x` : How and where does it get initiated? How is it defined? What will be the output of the program? How does it get it's input?
And what does the `|` resemble?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @BlkPengu: That syntax is a "list comprehension". In general, `[x | xs]` means "`x` where `x` is from the set `xs`". The above would be equivalent to the math notation "{ x | x is in the range 2 to n - 1 and n is divisible by x }". (Indeed, the Haskell syntax is meant to evoke set notation.)

Comment: thank you for the quick answer @mipadi. can you tell me something about the questions regarding input and output?

Comment: @mipadi Don't you mean `[ x | x <- xs ]`?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: I do. :-)

Comment: @BlkPengu there is no input/otput in this program. It's just a function definition. No more, no less.